# Prepositional or Accusative after на

Tags: грамматика, падежи

In **журналист писал на разные темы**, why is *разные темы* in the accusative case?

Supposing **The journalist wrote on various themes** is a good translation, shouldn't the prepositional case follow *на* here?

Comment: **Писал на разные темы** is correct, and I'm not sure I understand why you think prepositional would be better here.

Comment: In this case, I would translate `темы` as "topics" rather than "themes".

Comment: Interesting question... "Журналист писал на бумаге" uses the prepositional case... Unfortunately, I can't give you any explanation other than "accusative is correct here".

Comment: Perhaps rephrasing "he covered various topics" will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short answer is: preposition **"на"** when used in this meaning need a noun in the accusative case.
In this sentence [**на**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B0) seems to fit next meaning: *indicating a purpose of a thing or an action* sixth item in the link. (at least, on my opinion it's the closest meaning from the list). There are examples from the link:

> Разрешение на проезд.  `разрешение чтобы проехать`
>   Билет на самолёт.   `билет для того чтобы сесть на самолёт`
>   Отдать ребёнка на воспитание.  `отдать для того чтобы воспитывали`
>   Наряд на погрузку.  `наряд для того чтобы погружали`
>   Просить на пропитание.  `просить чтобы пропитаться`
>   Учиться на инженера. `учиться для того чтобы стать инженером`

From these examples, it's seen, that a noun always in the accusative case when **на** is used in this meaning (though I can't assert that there are no exceptions).
**писать на тему** seems to fit this meaning because looked as purpose here, we can change it to **писать чтобы раскрыть тему**

Why it turned out in such using, is a question more to linguists.

**UPD** I have also found an [article](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6) about conflicting between cases (including conflicting between accusative and prepositional cases) in Russian. But I'm not ready to translate it here.

Comment: I will just add some words from the article. The same idea can be expressed using different prepositions. Prepositions require different cases. Писать про что‐то (accusative ), писать о чем-то (prepositional)."на тему" is just the same as "про что‐то ".